# Hand Off Bot to Human using BotFramework (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have crated a server application using botframework in NodeJS and configured for web chat channel in botframework.

I want to validate the every reply that bot delivers to end user and those messages will be validated by human from an external web application.

How can we trigger the bot from external application and deliver the response to the exact user?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some resources to get you started, please let us know if you have any further questions.

•   [Build 2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/windows-developer-day) Bot Human Handoff
•   [Microsoft Real Life Code](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/06/30/bot-to-human-handover-in-node-js/) Bot to Human Handoff in Node.js
•   [Node.js](https://github.com/palindromed/Bot-HandOff) palindromed/Bot-HandOff
•   [F5 Blog](https://ankitbko.github.io/2017/03/human-handover-bot/) Transferring chat to a human agent using Microsoft Bot Framework

Comment: Thank Jason Sowers for your response, i have posted one more question related to bot framework, can you please check it?