# How to Escalate Bot Conversation to Skype for Business Users

Tags: botframework

We have a publicly facing bot that is working well. However what we'd like to do is if the bot was not able to address the problem, escalate it to a real person. The first of those ways is to a person or (preferably) a group in skype for business.  I'd like to have them be able to answer directly in skype.

We also need to able to have the bot be registered in our customer's skype for business tenant along with being able to communicate with ours.

Is this doable? If so, can someone point me to anything that will do it? The only documentation I could find says outbound is possible but gives no samples an seems to imply that it's either escalation or ability to register the bot in multiple tenants.

Comment: Some clues about your need in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human . There is 1 node.js demo and in its readme a link to the C# version

Comment: please see this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097170/hand-off-bot-to-human-using-botframework-nodejs/47099488#47099488) there are some great resources.  Let us know if you have follow up questions

Comment: Thanks. Any .net samples?  And I can't find the video referenced in the answer on the other thread.